# Pull data from rather large xml file

Tags: xml, database, ms-access

I work for a hospital and I need to create an inventory of different products we have, and want to include all the information about them.  I'm lucky in the fact that every medical device is cataloged by the FDA, and you can download in XML format.  The problem is the file is 8gb (and can be found here: https://accessgudid.nlm.nih.gov/download)

Where I'm not lucky, is that being on a hospital network, I'm extremely limited in programs I'm allowed to use.  I've spent a while researching how I can go about this, but every solution I've found involves using other software. All I can really use is access (and VBA).

The file is too large to create a database out of the whole thing.  You can download individual search responses from the website, so I tried doing it by manufacturer, and hit the size limit of Access after 3 (of about 50-100).

What I would like to do is to be able to search by a number of different terms (deviceid, reference, product name), have it search the database, and if it's not there, find it in the xml file and create a record out of it in the inventory database.  The problem is that most of those are nested 4 or 5 layers deep in the XML file.
Here is a link to the schema: https://accessgudid.nlm.nih.gov/download/schema

I'm rather unfamiliar with XML itself, but have a decent handle on SQL and databases in general.  I also have the benefit that speed isn't a huge requirement, and can easily have queries take upwards of 10 seconds to complete.

There is also an API available from the FDA, but unfortunately they only allow lookups via the deviceID, which isn't always available.  Adding records manually is another option, but again, device id isn't always available, and the FDA database contains information that's not on the packaging.

Is there any way to relatively quickly find information nested within an XML file that's too large to fit in memory, and without use of outside software (I can fly under the radar with some non-installation software, but still want to avoid it if it all possible.

Edit: Also, the data download is in 80 or so 100 meg XML files that don't appear to really be organized in any particular way.

Comment: I can't offer you an answer, but you can have my sympathy all day long. Having said that, I would probably try to create "views" or "indexes", so one file would just contain product name-deviceid pairs, another one would contain reference-deviceid pairs, and so on. Once you query that and have the deviceid, you can go to the FDA service.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.  So while looking at the data and trying to figure out how I can do what you suggested, I noticed that there's enormous amounts of wasted data (for ex:  100+ rows with 300+ character strings that are identical) and I'm wondering if I can't just shrink everything to a manageable size.  I'm just wondering if there's a way to feed a file into something, have it assign all the unique strings a number, then spit out a numbered list of the individual unique strings?

Comment: I'm now realizing that this question is probably better suited to creating a new thread

Comment: So I'm working through it on my own, and just have to say that being forced to use VBA through Excel to work with enormous text files in a way that has nothing to do with Excel is extremely clunky and painful.  All those with access to Visual Studio at work should thank their lucky stars!!